# Referencing font awesome icons in Rails link_to statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, font-awesome

How do I specifically modify the following Ruby code to work with a font awesome question mark icon instead of the link text labelled "info"? I'm not sure what the syntax would look like.

```
<%= link_to(“info”, :action => ‘info’) %></i>
```

PS: The line above is working in my app at the moment, as a regular link...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the block syntax supported by the rails link_to helpers.

```
<%= link_to(:action => 'info') do %>
  <i class="fa fa-question"></i>
<% end %>
```

Comment: or use the fa_icon helper inside the do/end syntax :D

Answer (score 1):

Font awesome has a couple helpers you could use in order to add an icon to your link. Here is the link for the helper documentation: https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails#helpers

In your case the could would look like this:

`link_to fa_icon('question-circle', text: "info"), :action => ‘info’`

Hope that helps out.